# Fade out / Transparency in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gradient, texture

I have a quick question regarding Photoshop, as I did not manage to get the same result as in the picture below.

https://ro.pinterest.com/pin/466755948863287781/

[image]

In the section, at the bottom the ground is like faded out, but not only in one direction (as if you would do a transparency mask). I tried to achieve the same result with the Erase Tool with different opacity levels and gradient masks, but it just does not look as good as there. In fact, it look terrible to me.

Can someone give me some tips on how to achieve such a fade out effect on a texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The trick was to create a simple mask and using different brush types (different shapes, like grass brush or something) to create this fade out effect using different opacity stages and brush sizes. Now I'm pretty satisfied with the answer.

Here is how it looks.

[image]

Comment: Cool! glad you figured it out. I was thinking Watercolor Brush or perhaps Concrete Textures but didn't have time to dig into it. Thanks for answering it too! Be sure to mark your answer right when it let's you